# More representative data set OR higher model evaluation metrics?

Tags: classification, dataset, data, churn

A colleague and I are working on a churn model and reached an impasse:

Our data set is for a global product. We've been asked to look at the US market only.

When we subset the data to the US only, the classifier evaluation metrics are lower than when we use the total global data set.

My colleague wants to use the global data set because the output metrics are higher. I consider this the wrong thing to do, we should limit the data to the US market only.

My thinking: Only use the data set that best represents the situation you are looking to explore. That is, we should only be using the data set filtered to the US market here.

As we're dealing with human shopper behavior here, there could be lots of localised factors that change from market from market - culture, salary, shopper behavior, localised competitors.

Is the approach to use the filtered data set correct? Are there papers, similar that talk to this point? Is there a useful term to search on Google for?

Comment: What is the kind of data (e.g., tabular, time series)? What classifier are you using? What is the difference in magnitude between the two datasets (global vs USA-only)? It is a multi-class classification problem? If so, perhaps the classifier on the global dataset is better on other classes, and this increases the metrics, whereas with a subset of it (USA-only) the model gets confused.

Comment: @0xedu The data is tabular, tree-based classification to predict the probability of someone churning. For magnitude, what are you thinking of, size of data set?

Comment: Just to understand better your scenario. You are predicting a class or a number? As for the magnitude, yes, just to have an insight into the proportions of the smaller dataset compared to the bigger one; that is, I'm not interested in how many bytes they occupy in memory.

Comment: Are your evaluation metrics measured for just the US?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @0xedu: We're predicting a number, probability of individual churning, then using a threshold to identify churners: i.e. if >0.7, high likelihood of churn. For magnitude, for the US we have 8k customers and global 100k. What is behind your question on magnitude out of interest?

Comment: @BenReiniger We've split the data and trained two models, one for US only and one for total global data, then evaluated each model independently of one another.

Comment: So the US model is being tested only on a US test set, and the global model is being tested on the global test set?

Comment: So, your problem is not a classification one, but a regression one? I must understand this issue so that I can formulate hopefully an answer. If you say that your problem is a classification one, then can I assume that if the threshold > 0.7 then class 1, otherwise 0? Please be more specific. Thank you.

Comment: @BenReiniger Correct: We have split the data set in two, one for global (including US) and one US only. We then train separate models on each data set.

Comment: I think that's problematic: if the goal is to understand the US market, you should only be scoring on the US market.  I think it's worth trying to train with the global data, to see if there's enough in common to produce a better model, but scoring should happen strictly on US, IMO.

Comment: @0xedu We're classifying churn / no churn as 1/0, so binary classification. We're using .predict_proba to get the probabilities of a customer being assigned to a class and using that as a threshold. So to identify customers with >0.6 probability of churning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @BenReiniger. I think what you're saying here is train using full data set, then use that model to predict for US market only, is that right? As the answer  below states, there's nothing to say the US market needs to be so unique.

Comment: I'm suggesting what Dave's answer says: try two models (as you have), one trained on US and one on global, but (as you haven't) to **score** each model on a US test set.  See how the two perform and then choose which to take.  I agree with Dave's response that both approaches have theoretical merit (data volume or data representativeness), and the best way to pick is to see how they both perform on the task you wish to perform.  But scoring models on different test sets is comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: First, I'm suggesting @BenReiniger's answer. Second, perhaps the dataset is unbalanced, and this leads to poor evaluations. In particular, perhaps the global market dataset is unbalanced towards a class, whereas the US-only dataset is balanced. Think about it: having, for example, 10% of the data with class 0 and the remaining 90% with class 1, and having a model that predicts well class 1, will have roughly 90% accuracy, but when testing that same model on a dataset which has 50%/50% for class 0/1 then will lead to more or less 50% accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider it a hyperparameter and tube it to the best value.

As you point out, there are multiple possibilities. Your stance of using only the most representative data has merit; the stance of using all available data has merit, since more data results in tighter estimates, and nothing says that Americans have to be so unique.

Therefore, go figure out which approach gives the best results.

Early evidence suggests that using more data results in better performance.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. Are you suggesting that the number of rows (or even countries) becomes a hyperparameter to then pass into grid search? [Based on the countries comment, I wonder what happens if more countries "similar" to the USA were included and then countries dissimilar to the USA were excluded]

Comment: I wasn’t thinking of being that formal about it, but sure, you could expand the set of possibilities and then search over the whole space like you might for other hyperparameters.